# Is it possible to write to input / read output from a detached subprocess?

Tags: python, python-3.7

I'm trying to manage a game server (a server for players to join, I didn't create the game) through a Python module. I noticed, however, that the server stops when the Python script stops to ask for input (from input()). Is there any way around this?

The server is ran as a subprocess:
`server = subprocess.Popen("D:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` followed by `server.stdin.write` calls to run the server exe file

The server seems to work fine if ran without a stdout pipe, but I still need to receive output from it without it stopping if possible. 
I apologize for the vague question and my lack of python knowledge.

Comment: Normally, you wouldn't want a server to call `input()`. It should be getting its inputs from the clients. If you _do_ need to take input from the user running the server, you will want to either want to move all the server stuff onto a background thread, or put `sys.stdin` into non-blocking mode so you can throw it into the same `selectors` or `asyncio` or whatever loop that you're using for the server. (Without even the vaguest idea of how you implemented your server, it's hard to say anything more specific than that.)

Comment: I should've been clearer. I didn't create the game. I'm launching a dedicated server for a Steam game and I'd like to try to have users in a Discord server send input to the server's stdin through discord commands. My problem is that the game server stops when the python script does (to wait for input).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to do two things:

- Service a subprocess's stdout.
- Wait for user input on `input`.

And you need to do them both simultaneously, and in something close to real time—while you block reading from the subprocess, the user can't enter any commands, and while you block reading from user input, the subprocess hangs on stalled pipe.

---

The simplest way to do this is to just use a thread for each.

Without seeing any code, it's hard to show a good example, but something like this:

```
def service_proc_stdout(proc):
    while True:
        buf = proc.stdout.read()
        do_proc_stuff(buf)

proc = subprocess.Popen(…)
t = threading.Thread(target=service_proc_stdout, args=(proc,))
t.start()

while True:
    command = input()
    do_command_stuff(command)
```

---

It sounds like your `do_command_stuff` is writing to `proc.stdin`. That may just work, but it's possible that `proc.stdin` may block if you push input into it too fast, preventing you from reading user input. If you need to solve that, just start a third thread:

```
def service_proc_stdin(q, proc):
    while True:
        msg = q.get()
        proc.stdin.write(msg)

q = queue.Queue()
tstdin = threading.Thread(target=service_proc_stdin, args=(q, proc))
tstdin.start()
```

… and now, instead of directly calling `proc.stdin.write(…)`, you call `q.put(…)`.

---

Threads aren't the *only* way to handle the concurrency here. For example, you could use an `asyncio` event loop, or a manual `selectors` loop around non-blocking pipes. But it's probably the simplest change, at least if you don't need to share or pass anything between the threads beyond messages you push onto a queue.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It's working just as intended. Sorry again for the unclear question!